# Query Optimisation in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I know this question is asked frequently here but I have some different requirements.

I want to get this output. I am getting this also with my logic but can this can be done in more simple and optimised way. To run this query faster.

Here is my query:

```
select 
    ISNULL('PortFolio Code: '+a.CPORTFOLIOCODE,'Grand Total') as [PortFolio Code],
    COUNT(SZCUSTOMERNO) as [Accounts],
    CAST(COUNT(SZCUSTOMERNO) * 100 / (Select COUNT(SZCUSTOMERNO) 
                                      from dbo.COL_TRN_AGREEMENT) 
                                      as nvarchar(50))+' %' as [%],
    sum(case when a.SZBUCKETCODE =1 then a.FOSAMT else 0 end ) as [Bucket :1],
    sum(case when a.SZBUCKETCODE =2 then a.FOSAMT else 0 end ) as [Bucket :2],
    sum(case when a.SZBUCKETCODE =3 then a.FOSAMT else 0 end ) as [Bucket :3],
    sum(a.FOSAMT) as [All Buckets] 
from 
    dbo.COL_TRN_AGREEMENT a 
group by 
    a.CPORTFOLIOCODE with rollup
```

I am getting this output

[image]

Can this be done using simple logic with faster execution or this is the simplest way.

Comment: I don't see any other way to do it. If you want to improve performance, post the query plan.

Comment: query plan as in the "execution plan" is required to help with optimizations (.sqlplan file as attachment is best IMO)

Comment: Since Select COUNT(SZCUSTOMERNO) from dbo.COL_TRN_AGREEMENT is static field that does not change with every row better declare a variable for that which will help in faster retrieval of data.

Comment: why a negative mark to this question. ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach, may not be faster, but you still have a choise to compare.

```
declare @cnt int
Select @cnt = COUNT(SZCUSTOMERNO) from dbo.COL_TRN_AGREEMENT

;with 
matrix (SZBUCKETCODE,Bucket_1,Bucket_2,Bucket_3) as 
       (select 1,1,0,0 union
        select 2,0,1,0 union
        select 3,0,0,1)
select isnull('PortFolio Code: '+a.CPORTFOLIOCODE,'Grand Total') as [PortFolio Code],
       COUNT(SZCUSTOMERNO) as [Accounts],
       cast(COUNT(SZCUSTOMERNO)*100/@cnt as nvarchar(50))+' %' as [%],
       sum(a.FOSAMT*m.Bucket_1) as [Bucket :1],
       sum(a.FOSAMT*m.Bucket_2) as [Bucket :2],
       sum(a.FOSAMT*m.Bucket_3) as [Bucket :3],
       sum(a.FOSAMT) as [All Buckets] 
  from dbo.COL_TRN_AGREEMENT a 
  join matrix m
    on m.SZBUCKETCODE = a.SZBUCKETCODE 
 group by a.CPORTFOLIOCODE with rollup
```

Comment: Its not working . giving this error

'Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group'.
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.'

Comment: Hey its not giving error now but not giving exact output. It is giving duplicate portfolio code data.

Comment: There are not duplicated rows, they are rollup rows. Wait for a minitue.

Comment: yes but when I remove rollup it is also not giving me the final summation of columns

Comment: You could union the final summation row instead of `with rollup`. But still have a choice to use total count as an variable, check it:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dcdc4/6

Comment: Voila this works. Thanks But how can we say or check this query is optimised or the one which I have written.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61726/discussion-between-jaugar-chang-and-ams).