# how to sum data in one cell and have bifurcated values in multiple columns in sql

Tags: sql-server

My data is like this:

```
DateNo     GenreId    GenreName    ChannelID    Channel    TotalSpots 
1            5         Sports      10386      STAR SPORTS4     4 
2            5         Sports      10386      STAR SPORTS4     7
3            5         Sports      10386      STAR SPORTS4     8
4            5         Sports      10386      STAR SPORTS4     11
5            5         Sports      10386      STAR SPORTS4     12
6            5         Sports      10388      STAR SPORTS1     3
7            5         Sports      10388      STAR SPORTS1     10
8            5         Sports      10388      STAR SPORTS1     11
9            5         Sports      10388      STAR SPORTS1     14
10           5         Sports      10388      STAR SPORTS1     15
```

Now i want to have genereid, generename, channelid , channelname, sum of totalspots (group by channelid) and then dateno values as column with totalspots for that particular dateno as its value

eg :

```
GenreId GenreName ChannelID Channel      Sum_totalspots  1 2 3  4  5 6  7  8  9 10 
5       Sports    10386     STAR SPORTS4 43              4 7 8 11 12 0  0  0  0  0 
5       Sports    10388     STAR SPORTS1 53              0 0 0  0  0 3 10 11 14 15
```

Please someone help me to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please show output result template which you expected

Comment: i think you want to [rollup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305(v=sql.90).aspx) the results?

Comment: GenreId GenreName ChannelID Channel TotalSpots 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 <br>
5 Sports 10386 STAR SPORTS4 72 4 7 8 11 12 0 0 0 0 0 <br>
5 Sports 10388 STAR SPORTS1 97 0 0 0 0 0 3 10 11 14 15

Answer (score 0):

Try this sql query

```
SELECT GenreId,GenreName,ChannelID,Channel,SUM(TotalSpots)  FROM YourTableName
GROUP BY GenreId,GenreName,ChannelID,Channel
```

Comment: dateno is one column i want to have its value as column header and totalspot for that dateno as its value i used this query 
SELECT * into ##temp1 from 
##temp as  s
PIVOT
(
    min(totalspots)
    FOR dateNo  IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10])
)AS p m getting totalspot values for dateno column but how can i get sum(totalspot) aslo in one column for dat cahnnelid

Answer (score 0):

No need of using PIVOT, sum totalSpots case by DateNo would be enough:

```
SELECT 
    GenreId,GenreName,ChannelID,Channel
   ,SUM(TotalSpots)  
   ,SUM(CASE DateNo=1 THEN TotalSpots END) AS [1]
   ...
   ,SUM(CASE DateNo=10 THEN TotalSpots END) AS [10]
FROM YourTableName
GROUP BY 
    GenreId,GenreName,ChannelID,Channel
```

Comment: this is a bit helpful but if i dont know how many rows are there in DateNo column and what is the exact value in that column then? i want to generate columns dynamically

Comment: No sql can generate columns dynamically, even PIVOT. Generate and excute dynamical sql can only by using store procedure or other  program language.

Comment: @SanyaKherani If you want more flexible way, here is another approach you could referece (http://stackoverflow.com/a/25987136/3630826).